# Facebook javascript login not redirecting to new page in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using facebook javascript SDK login. When i login through chrome it authorizes user login but the document.location = 'logincallback.php' doesn't work. But the page is redirecting in mozilla. Please help me out ?

```
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {

          // Logged into your app and Facebook.
          testAPI(response);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
        } else {
          // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
          // they are logged into this app or not.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
        }
      }

      // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
      // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
      // code below.
      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }


      // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
      // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
      // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
      // the callback you provide.  They can be:
      //
      // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
      // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
      // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
      //    your app or not.
      //
      // These three cases are handled in the callback function.
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB._https = true;
      FB.init({
        appId      : '1457599654539273',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                            // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
      // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
      function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

          console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            document.location = "logincallback.php" ;
        });

      }

     function Login()
        {

            FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        window.location ="logincallback.php";
         }
         else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    },{scope: 'public_profile,email'});

        } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the `document.location = 'logincallback.php'` doesn't work

That’s because that is just wrong, and only works in Firefox by accident resp. due to its error tolerance in that regard.

First of all, it’s `window.location`, not `document.location`.

And *overwriting* that whole object is wrong as well - you want to set the `href` property of that object instead.

So the correct way to do this is:

```
window.location.href = 'logincallback.php'
```

Comment: Well then you need to do some basic debugging … first of all, have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: no errors in console too. It is working perfectly fine in firefox but not in chrome

Comment: Log the `response` object to console at the very beginning of the callback function, and inspect it in console. Any API error messages in there?